# i have to find many location along with latitude and longitude values from a google map and save into database

Tags: javascript

suppose if i give any one place latitude and longitude value,i need to get many locations by incrementing longitude or latitude values.and that should be save in a database.
In my program am incrementing longitude value by 0.05 and i keep latitude constanst.
i don't know how to save javascript values in database ???

> ```
> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
> <head>
>     <title></title>
> </head>
>
>
> <body>
>
>     Latitude:
>     <input type="text" id="txtLatitude" value="" name="latitude" />
>     Longitude:
>     <input type="text" id="txtLongitude" value="" name="longitude" />
>     Location:
>     <input type="text" id="txtLocation" value="" />
>     <input type="button" value="Get Address" onclick="GetAddress()" />
>
> </form>
>     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
>     <script type="text/javascript">
>
>         function GetAddress() {
>             var lat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtLatitude").value);
>             var lng = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtLongitude").value);
>
>             var lngg;
>
>           for( var i=1;i<5;i++)
>            {  
>             lng+=.05;//incremented longitude
>
>            var count=i;  
>            alert("lat:"+lat+",longi:"+lng+",count:"+count);
>             var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
>           var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
>             geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
>
>
>                 if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
>                     if (results[1]) {
>
>                       var  r=results[1].formatted_address;
>
>
>                         document.getElementById("txtLocation").value=r; 
>                         alert(r+",count"+count);
>
>                    }
>                 }
>
>             });
>
>         }
>
>         }
>
>     </script>
>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```